# Ordering by a field in reverse side foreign key in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models

```py
class Question(models.Model):
    content=models.TextField()

    ...



class Answer(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DatetimeField(auto_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, ... )
    content = models.TextField()
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, ....)

    ...

    class meta:
        unique_together=('author','question')
```

in the database I have a set of questions and answers. answers are linked to their authors.
unique_together ensures the user can give an answer only once to a question.

`usr_1` Is a user instance that has answers to some questions that I can retrieve by:

`qst_qs=Question.objects.filter(answer__author=usr_1)`

I want to **sort questions in `qst_qs` according to the `created_at` field in `usr_1`'s answer in each question**.

*Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code:

```
qst_qs=Question.objects.filter(answer__author=usr_1).order_by('answer__created_at')
```